# Azure devops deployment failure : TypeError: Cannot read property 'scmUri' of undefined

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

I have been facing this issue particularly today while deploying my application to the azure environment using Azure Devops.

One of the deployment task fails with the following eror message:

> ##[debug]Deployment Failed with Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scmUri' of undefined

When I retry to deploy a couple of times it succeeds and deployment is successfully done.

What is the issue causing this error?

Comment: We are seeing the exact same error today for the first time... Maybe there is a technical issue with Azure DevOps today?

Comment: @Kjensen Then it should be from azure devops definitely. i was wondering since it worked for the same tasks in another environment

Comment: We're escalating to MS - seems to be their end.

Comment: we've seen the issue for a few days. It's non-deterministic -- sometimes it works.

Comment: Related issue was raised on Developer Community here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/359862/release-pipeline-inconsistently-fails.html

Comment: @Sajeetharan it's certainly blocking our ability to release to production.  And I expect many others as well.  We can't find any way of "working around" it short-term.

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=17825) might be a factor at play here

Comment: Today is the first time I've seen this error and it's definitely transient; it occurs in different tasks at different times. I was finally able to get a successful release after 3 deploys.

Comment: Issue observed in UK South also

Comment: Voting to close this question, as the problem is now resolved and no longer reproducible.

Comment: It's happening again right now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microsoft is aware:

> We're investigating Intermittent failures of Release Pipelines in West Europe.
>
> Customer using Azure App Service Deploy task in their Release Pipelines might see intermittent errors like: "##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'scmUri' of undefined"
>
> Retrying the release may succeed.
>
> Next Update: Before Wednesday, October 17th 2018 15:50 UTC

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=17835.

Hopefully we'll get a response soon.

Comment: The ms blogs states that this is happening in West Europe, but  I am getting the problem occurring in North Europe alose.

Comment: US East is also affected. We started seeing these yesterday afternoon.

Comment: US West is also affected now.

Answer (score 3):

The latest report from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=17835:

> Final Update: Wednesday, October 17th 2018 20:14 UTC
>
> We’ve confirmed that all systems are back to normal as of 2018/10/17 19:35 UTC. Our logs show the incident started on 2018/10/17 13:42 UTC and that during the 5 hours and 53 minutes that it took to resolve the issue. Customers using Azure App Service Deploy task in their Release Pipelines might see intermittent errors like: "##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'scmUri' of undefined". Sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused.
>
> - Root Cause: Initial diagnosis from the Azure Web Apps team points to
>     issues with a few of their back end nodes sending bad api responses.
> - Chance of Re-occurrence: Medium
> - Lessons Learned: We are working both
>     minimizing resource-intensive activities in our post-deployment
>     steps, and are also working targeting monitors specifically to detect
>     post-deployment issues in the future.
> - Incident Timeline: 5 hours & 23
>     minutes – 2018/10/17 13:42 UTC through 2018/10/17 19:35 UTC
>
> Sincerely,
>   Randy